# Convert Int16 array to base64 string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, base64, data-conversion

I need to send audio data to an API which requires a base64 string as input.

Therefore I'm looking for a way to convert an `Int16Array` to a `base64 string`. Is there a simple procedure to do that? All methods that I've found so far applied to uint8 data...

Comment: Look at the inbuilt function btoa() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `btoa` seems indeed a piece of the pipe I need. From what I understand, the input needs to be `uint8`? I guess I will need 2 unsigned 8-bit integers to code each of my signed 16-bit integer, is that correct? I'm a bit lost here too...